# Create a python function based on previous and next element of a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
       a         b      c     Label       Value
0  43.91 -0.041619  43.91         B       30.25
1  43.91 -0.041619  43.91         A       43.91
2  43.39  0.011913  43.91         B       43.91
3  45.56 -0.048801  43.91         B       30.52
4  45.43  0.002857  43.91         B       43.91
5  45.33  0.002204  43.91         A       43.91
6  45.68 -0.007692  43.91         A       22.21
7  46.37 -0.014992  43.91         B       43.91
...
```

What I want to do is to create a function that does something like below, for each row:

```
function =

if next element (+ 1) of column Value == column Value  AND previous element (- 1) of column Value != column Value AND column Value > 40 :

return True

else:
return False
```

And then create a new column based on this function:

```
if df.Label = A:
  df[Value reached] = function

else:
  df[Value reached] = False
```

Is it possible to implement this on python and achieve something like the following output?

```
       a         b      c     Label       Value   Value reached
0  43.91 -0.041619  43.91         B       30.25           False
1  43.91 -0.041619  43.91         A       43.91            True
2  43.39  0.011913  43.91         B       43.91           False
3  45.56 -0.048801  43.91         B       30.52           False
4  45.43  0.002857  43.91         B       43.91           False
5  45.33  0.002204  43.91         A       43.91           False
6  45.68 -0.007692  43.91         A       22.21           False
7  46.37 -0.014992  43.91         B       43.91           False
...
```

Comment: Look into the `shift()` function of pandas: [Shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html)

Comment: then why is True in row 1?

Comment: @ansev because in row 1 column 'Value' is equal to the next row, different from the previous, and then also has 'Label' equal to A

Comment: @ansev sorry, I mistakenly wrote == instead of != in the second statement. Now I edited it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, [`Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html)

```
df['Value reached'] = (df['Value'].ne(df['Value'].shift()) & 
                       df['Value'].eq(df['Value'].shift(-1)) & 
                       df['Label'].eq('A') &
                       df['Value'].gt(40))

print(df)
```

---

```
       a         b      c     Label       Value   Value reached
0  43.91 -0.041619  43.91         B       30.25           False
1  43.91 -0.041619  43.91         A       43.91            True
2  43.39  0.011913  43.91         B       43.91           False
3  45.56 -0.048801  43.91         B       30.52           False
4  45.43  0.002857  43.91         B       43.91           False
5  45.33  0.002204  43.91         A       43.91           False
6  45.68 -0.007692  43.91         A       22.21           False
7  46.37 -0.014992  43.91         B       43.91           False
```